# Shell script runs manually, but not with cron

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, cron

In my sudo crontab, edited with `sudo crontab -e`, I have:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
40 4 * * * /bin/bash /usr/bin/verify-miab-backup.sh
```

That script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date` > /home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log
echo `id -u -n` >> /home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log
export PASSPHRASE=$(cat /dozer/eandb/miab_22-04/secret_key.txt)
duplicity verify --log-file=/var/log/duplicity_backblaze_verify.log file:///dozer/eandb/miab_backblaze_backups/ /dev/null && echo "miab_last_verify_time_seconds `date +"%s"`" > /etc/grafana-text-file-collectors/miab_verify.prom
```

The first two lines were to help try to debug this issue. That `/home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log` file contains:

```
Mon 10 Apr 04:40:01 BST 2023
root
```

so it looks like the file is being run and by root. The third line takes the secret key from a file and stores it into PASSPHRASE (is that okay in a cron job?) and then the fourth line uses that passphrase to verify a backup.

If I look at the .prom file, though:

```
$ cat /etc/grafana-text-file-collectors/miab_verify.prom
miab_last_verify_time_seconds 1681077406
```

that time corresponds to Sunday, 9 April 2023 22:56:46, which is when I last ran it manually.

Running it manually with `sudo verify-miab-backup.sh`, everything works as expected. `/home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log` contains:

```
$ cat /home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log 
Mon 10 Apr 14:10:15 BST 2023
root
```

and

```
cat /etc/grafana-text-file-collectors/miab_verify.prom
miab_last_verify_time_seconds 1681132381
```

is Monday, 10 April 2023 14:13:01, as you would expect.

I am guessing I am doing something obviously wrong with permissions or using variables in a way that is not permitted in a cron job, but I am just not sure where. Any help would be appreciated.

Looking at previous questions on here:

- [shell script works manually, but not with cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124337/shell-script-works-manually-but-not-with-cron)
  -- I have used the Bash shebang and called with bash specifically, to make sure I'm not caught by any "bashisms".
- I've used the full path to the file as suggested here: [Shell script runs fine by itself, but not in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279551/shell-script-runs-fine-by-itself-but-not-in-cron)
- I added /bin/bash before my command [Bash script runs fine, but not in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477677/bash-script-runs-fine-but-not-in-cron)
- I could not see anything in [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) that would be relevant to me.

Many thanks!

Comment: `/bin/bash` in crontab is unnecessary since you are using the "shebang" in your shell script. However, please try to use the full path of `duplicity` on the fifth line. Also you should redirect stdout and stderr of your script to a file in the crontab, so that you can easily see any (error) output produced by the script.

Comment: In the 4th link above, did you check the difference between your user environment and the cron environment in which you are trying to run the job. See answer headed Different Environment

Comment: @FedKad you were right *facepalm*. While I was worried about the path in cron, I missed the path to duplicity in the fifth line. Adding the full path to that fixed my issue. Many thanks -- if you add that point from your comment into the beginning of your answer below then I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1):

I would just put the following in *root*'s *crontab*:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
40 4 * * * /usr/bin/verify-miab-backup.sh
```

And would change the contents of your script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
{
  echo -e "\n=== $(date) - $0 started - $(id -u -n) ==="
  export PASSPHRASE=$(cat /dozer/eandb/miab_22-04/secret_key.txt)
  duplicity verify ...
  echo -e "\n=== $(date) - $0 finished ==="
} &>> /home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log
```

This way, ***all*** expected and not expected output (*stdout*) and error messages (*stderr*) will be appended to the end of your log file (`/home/mythbuntu/last_verify_miab_run.log`) and you will be able to debug your script much more easily. You should put any other commands inside the curly brackets (`{}`), so that you will not lose anything.

I would also determine the full path of the `duplicity` command (possibly `/usr/bin/duplicity`) and use the full path in the 5th line above, in case the process running my *cron* script has not included the directory containing `duplicity` in its `PATH` and I see a related error message in the log above.